# An action I performed before becoming a moderator is listed under /admin/history

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, moderation-history

[My moderation history at Anime.SE has an unusual entry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/admin/history/1908) (link only viewable by other Anime.SE mods and SE employees, of course):

[image]

The linked post is [Which episodes of Konjiki no Gash Bell are essential?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/posts/19929/revisions).

Why is a rather mundane action that I performed weeks before receiving a diamond listed under my moderation history? (It's just this one action, too; nothing else prior to Apr 6 at 14:29 is listed there.)

Comment: Not even other edits? That's super odd.

Comment: The precedent is that diamonds are retroactive, see deletions - if you vote to delete a post as a normal user, then get elected/appointed, your vote becomes a moderator-vote and other people can't vote to undelete the post.

Comment: @Undo I'm aware of that, but I don't see what that has to do with this.

Comment: @senshin - If I look back through my mod-log, it only goes back as far March 25, and I cannot access the history beyond that. I suspect that the mod-log only keeps the last 30 days of 50 events, or something. I suspect you would have more details if it went back further. an official answer will confirm that, or not.

Comment: @rolfl You appear to be right - based on the other two mods on my site, it looks like the mod log only keeps up to 50 events. However, since I was only recently instated as a moderator, I only have 17 total events on my log at this time, so that can't be the whole explanation.

Comment: @senshin - that's why I suggested the 30-day limit too. March11 is a giveaway for that.

Comment: @rolfl That can't be. Other moderators on my site have mod logs going back 47 and 71 days (which are the points at which the 50-event cutoff hits for them).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The logic used to determine moderator actions is... Pretty weird. It essentially boils down to "Find all the posts with flags that have been touched by the moderator" - which makes some amount of sense, but manages to exclude both posts where flags were handled but not modified, and posts that were modified but don't have flags. Oh, and it also has no concept of when you were or were not a moderator; as far as it knows, anyone currently a moderator has always been a mod and anyone not currently a moderator has never been a mod.

So what we have here is a case where a post was flagged, the flag was handled (by a different moderator) and then you modified it. Now that you're a mod, that looks to the system like a moderator action.

I'm leaving this marked as a bug because, frankly, I think this logic is pretty broken and want to spend time fixing it at some point.